# Save json image in android storage

Tags: android, android-json, android-internal-storage

I am loading data from sever (JSON). I am able to load the data & images but the problem is when there is no internet available i can't check the data?

So how can i save the images (also text) loaded from json in android storage?

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://deliverit.co.in/test.php?tablename=shakestable",
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");
                                deliverName = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                                deliverPrice = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                                deliverImage = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject products = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    deliverName[i] = products.getString("name");
                                    deliverPrice[i] = products.getString("price");
                                    String url = products.getString("image");
                                    deliverImage[i] = url;

                                }


                                int a = response.getInt("success");
                                Log.e("YASH", String.valueOf(a));

                                String m = response.getString("message");
                                Log.e("YASH", m);

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(a)+"\n"+m, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), deliverName, deliverPrice, deliverImage);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Log.e("CHECKKK", deliverName[2]);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR\n" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
            RequestQueue requestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    });
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] imgs = {};
String[] name = {};
String[] price = {};
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader mImageLoader;

public Adapter(Context context, String[] name, String[] price, String[] imgs) {
    super(context, R.layout.movies_row_layout, name);

    this.c = context;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.imgs = imgs;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView deliver_name;
    TextView deliver_price;
    NetworkImageView deliver_image;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_row_layout, null);
    }
    //View Holder Object
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.deliver_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DELIVERname);
    holder.deliver_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DELIVERprice);
    holder.deliver_image = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);

    //ASSIGN DATA
    mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(c)
            .getImageLoader();

    mImageLoader.get(imgs[position], ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.deliver_image,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable
                    .ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.deliver_image.setImageUrl(imgs[position], mImageLoader);
    /*if (holder.deliver_image == null) {
        //holder.deliver_image.setImageBitmap(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        holder.deliver_image.setImageBitmap(imgs[position]);
    }*/
    holder.deliver_price.setText(price[position]);
    holder.deliver_name.setText(name[position]);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) has the information you need.

Comment: How about converting image into Base64 and storing it in preference or sqlite. ? And resync when internet is available.